# How do processor cores share/run queued threads?

Tags: java, windows, multithreading, processor, cpu-cores

I have a processor with two cores c1 and c2. I have seven threads t0, t1, t2, t3, t4, t5 and t6. t0 is the main thread.

From t0 I create t1 and t2 to handle certain tasks from data d0 obtained from t0. Both t1 and t2 work to produce data d0a and d0b they then feed to the main thread to produce d0a + d0b = data d1 (i.e. threads t1 and t2 wait (`join()`) for each other to be idle before sharing their intel (d0a and d0b obtained from d0) with the main thread to produce d1).

In order to help speed up the process at t1 it spawns thread t3 and t4 to help produce d0a likewise the process at t2 also spawns t5 and t6 to help produce d0b.

Let’s assume c1 handles t1, t3 and t4 then c2 handles t2, t5 and t6 by default

Say t1 with the assistance of t3 and t4 after producing d0a finished way ahead of the commencement of the process at t2. Would c1 help c2 finish up the process at t2 for example by handling one of it’s sub threads (t5 or t6).

Can processor cores start queued threads whenever threads assigned to them are idle.

This question is particularly tagged with java and windows because I am especially interested in how it applies. Other answers are also welcome

Comment: The OS (much less the CPU) has no idea what you're doing. If your threads are blocking each other (or blocked on I/O) the OS won't schedule them. If they're runnable (i.e. not blocked on something) it'll schedule them according to their priorities to whatever cores it deems fit.

Comment: Does the OS schedule threads or just processes? If the latter, who decides which thread in a process gets the CPU?

Comment: It depends on the OS.  If the OS can only schedule processes (i.e., "threads" are a user-space artifact) then the program running in the process will have to implement thread scheduling, likely by using an existing threads library - and probably using only the single CPU that the process is running on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can processor cores start queued threads...

Processor cores know nothing about threads. Processor cores execute streams of instructions. That's all they do.

The operating system *scheduler* knows about threads, and in particular, it knows the operational state of each thread. In some hypothetical OS, there are states called `running`, `runnable` (the thread wants to run but it lacks a CPU to run on), and `blocked` (the thread is waiting for something.) In a real OS, there may be different kinds of `blocked`, and there may be other states like `dead`, but we don't need to talk about those here.*

The OS also has a number of *queues*† that hold the contexts of non-`running` threads; There is a *run queue* that contains all of the `runnable` threads, and there typically is a different queue for each different reason that a thread might be `blocked`. (E.g., for each mutex lock, there is a queue of threads waiting to acquire the lock.)

The job of the OS scheduler is to decide when to *preempt* some running thread A, and choose a different `runnable` thread B to take its place. The scheduler;

- Interrupts (i.e., takes control of) the CPU that is running thread A,
- Changes thread A's state from `running` to `runnable`,
- Moves the thread A's context to the back of the run queue,
- Removes thread B from the run queue,
- Changes the state of thread B from `runnable` to `running`,
- Loads thread B's context onto the CPU, and
- lets the CPU return to executing application code.

> ...whenever threads assigned to them are idle?

Threads are never idle.‡ Threads either are `blocked` or `runnable` if not `running`. A *CPU* can be idle if there are no `runnable` threads that can be moved onto it. When the CPU is idle, it typically executes the operating system's *idle loop,* which looks like,

```java
while (true) {
    putCPUIntoLowPowerState();
}
```

The only way out of the idle loop is for the CPU to be interrupted, as described above.

---

* Java's [`Thread.State`](https://cr.openjdk.java.net/%7Eiris/se/17/latestSpec/api/java.base/java/lang/Thread.State.html) enumeration does not recognize any difference between `running` and `runnable`. Those both are wrapped up in `Thread.State.RUNNABLE`. Also, Java splits my `blocked` into `Thread.State.BLOCKED` (the thread is waiting to enter a `synchronized` block) and `Thread.State.WAITING` (the thread is waiting for any other reason.)

† Not actually strict FIFO queues (thanks @NateEldredge), but "queue" is the traditional name. They are the containers in which threads reside when they await whatever it is they are waiting for. The scheduler may consider various factors (e.g., the thread's priority) besides just how long the thread has been waiting when deciding which thread to take from one queue and move to a CPU or to another queue.

‡ I mean that from the point of view of the OS scheduler. An *application* might consider one of its threads to be "idle," but the OS knows nothing about what the application threads are supposed to do. As far as the OS is concerned, a thread either is `running`, or it is `runnable`, or it is `blocked`.

Comment: To †: in particular, one might mention that the OS's run queues are *not* strictly FIFO.  The choice of the next thread to be run depends on a lot of factors (time previously used, priority, etc, etc), with lots of heuristic algorithms to try to maximize performance.  You typically don't expect to be able to predict it in any way.

Comment: A "priority queue" is a type of queue, and more advanced scheduling criteria determine which task is currently at the head of the queue.  (Or on a multi-core system, scheduling is a distributed algorithm, with kernel code running on each core deciding what that core should run next.  So the core that was already running a task is more likely to keep running it, even if it has to handle an interrupt.)

Comment: what state would a thread be in the context of the OS if it’s paused by calling `join()` or `wait()`… `runnable`?

Comment: @LiNKeR, `Thread.State.RUNNABLE` means that there is _no_ reason (none that the JRE or JVM know of) why the thread should not be running on a CPU; The state of a thread that is waiting to `join()` some other thread, is `WAITING`. Same goes for a thread that is waiting in a `wait()` call or, for a thread that is waiting for pretty much any `java.util.concurrent` object. (But I don't know for sure about `java.util.concurrent.ReentrantLock`. I haven't tried that experiment.)